# How to know when enter key is pressed in C

Tags: c, serial-port, avr, atmega

I am trying to communicate with a computer through serial communication with an micro-controller (AVR). I am programming in C, and I cannot figure out how to determine if the user has pressed the enter key in the terminal and was wondering if someone would be able to help me out.

Comment: Actually there is no answer to your question unless you give us some more details. Where is your programm running ? On the AVR microcontroller ? On a PC with Windows ? On a Macintosh ? On some linux system or maybe even on a Cray XMP computer ?

Comment: which terminal emulator are you using to communicate with the AVR over the serial port? Check whether it sends a `CR` or `CR`+`LF`. This is usually a configurable setting in most Terminal emulators. Once you determine the settings, simply check for that character(or pair in case of CR+LF) to arrive in plain-text i.e. ASCII on the receiving-end i.e. on the serial-port of your AVR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a good question with more details.  It sounds like you want to detect at the AVR when the user presses enter at the PC?  And that you are using a serial line between the two.

Please provide a copy of the C code running on the AVR.  If possible distill or simplify it as much as possible to highlight this particular question.

Finally, on the AVR are you setting an LED on, after the AVR receives a `CR` or `CR`+`LF`?